# Laravel: Distinct dropdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to make my dropdown have distinct value.

However, im getting an error saying

**"array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements"**

Please help?

**Here's my function in my dropdown**

```
$sections = Section1::distinct()->select('name')->lists('name','id');
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Virgil, but I think you code is incomplete, because we are unable to see the line where `array_combine` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `select` in your query. Just use:

```
$sections = Section1::distinct()->lists('name','id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sections = Section1::groupBy('name')->lists('name', 'id');
```

If your distinct clause is run against a column that is not the primary key, try using `groupBy` instead of `distinct`, then grab the list from there. My code is un-tested: If it is not working, try the other way around as well.

```
$sections = Section1::lists('name', 'id')->groupBy('name');
```